# Set different background color using Rich

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, rich

I found useful package [rich](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich). And want to use it in the next way:
drawing in different colors words in sentence and at different background colors.
I use next code:

```
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()
console.print('[green]some[/green] [#F47983]text[/#F47983]')
```

This way I can set any color for any word:

[image]

But I don't know, how to set different background colors. I tried `background=` , `bg:` and `backgrounp-color` - this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the word "on" to introduce the background color. For example:

```
print("[bold green on blue]Fear is the mind-killer[/]")
```

Also if you want to use hex codes:

```
print('[green on #F47983]some[/] [#F47983]text[/]')
```

See https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style.html for how to define styles.

Comment: It works! Thank you!
Furthermore, it works next way too: `console.print('[green on #F47983]some[/green on #F47983] [#F47983]text[/#F47983]') `
I added info to your answer :)

Comment: but how would you change the color of whole console in python.this only changes the background colour of the text we print.

Comment: Only way would be to set your terminal theme. The color codes will only have an effect on text that is subsequently written.