# Set the background of python console to an rgb value?

Tags: python, console-application, rich

I'm working on a little side project console-based python script. I'm using a module called rich to add colours but i was wondering if you could also set the background colour as well.

I know the `color` command exists but it's very limited.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This probably has already been answered, try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932477/set-different-background-color-using-rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the background to yellow on supported consoles:

```
print("\033]11;#ffff00\007")
```

The pattern is: `"\033]11;#rrggbb\007"`, where `rr`, `gg` and `bb` are the red, green and blue values in hexadecimal ranging from 0x00 to 0xFF.

Comment: Alright, I'll try this. I've also used hex before.